# Duplicate Rows in SQL (when linking 3 tables)

Tags: mysql, sql

when I link three of my SQL tables together (users, details, system) - it duplicates the results? However, when I link two SQL tables, it shows me the correct amount of linked data. I do not understand why my results are doubled when I join the three.
Heres the code I used to connect the tables:

Can someone please help me see where I've gone wrong?

Here are some screenshots of the three sets of data in my tables

[image: What its meant to be], but when I do the search query, it shows me double the amount of data.

![See that it has doubles =][2]

Comment: I see no duplicates in the result set.  Your question is not clear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Look at the bottom picture. The user 'dannii', has her results printed 4 times when it should be only twice. it is the same data, but reversed!

Comment: . . The rows look different to me.

Comment: on your "details' Table , user_id = 2 has 2 rows. which causing to have duplicate like records in final results.

Comment: You need `code  group by user_id ` since one user if I understand,it wright has many details!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DISTINCT` key in sql if you need 'unique' results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.user_id, users.user_email, system.date, system.time, system.table_layout, details.party_size, details.children_no, details.diets, 
details.occassion, details.more FROM users 
  Join system on users.user_id = system.id 
    Join details on system.id = details.ID
ORDER BY users.user_id
```

This however will not change your current result as it is already unique as pointed out by Gordon Linoff.

You can play around with the query

```
SELECT users.user_id, users.user_email, system.date, system.time, system.table_layout, details.party_size, details.children_no, details.diets, 
details.occassion, details.more FROM users 
  Join system on users.user_id = system.id 
    Join details on system.id = details.ID
ORDER BY users.user_id
WHERE [table].[column] = (SELECT DISTINCT [column] FROM [table])
```

Where the [column] is the column that should be unique in the [table].
You can combine multiple `WHERE x = (select y from z)` clauses to refine your results.

Comment: Hello! That did work in removing the duplicate rows, however, it wrongly assigned the tables together. As user_id 2 could have multiple data in the other two tables, but your SQL only allows one user to have one set of data

Comment: Clearified my answer @hello123

Comment: As i said play around with the Distinct clause, if that cannot help you you could try split your query up into multiple queries and use for example php code to refine your results @hello123

Answer (score 0):

Hey you just need to join the tables by the unique id so please use the below code you will get unique list

```
SELECT users.user_id, users.user_email, system.date, system.time, system.table_layout, details.party_size, details.children_no, details.diets, details.occassion, details.more FROM users Join system on users.user_id = system.user_id Join details on  users.user_id = details.user_id  ORDER BY users.user_id
```

Comment: The users.user_id,  system.user_id, details.user_id  should be same in all cases and users.user_id should be unique

Comment: the users.user_id is unique, and they are all the same.

Answer (score 0):

How the value coming as "Other" in column occasion ?
I can see there are two set of rows created for same user but the columns Party_size, children_no,  "occasion" have different values, so how can it be the duplicate rows?

Comment: If you look closely, they're the same data but with the date reversed. It is repeated. E.g. on the 2nd and 3rd row, the second half is the exact same. when this data was only inputted the once